# Google map not showing on Android 2.3 device

Tags: android, google-maps

I recently learn how to implements a **Google map** in my app. It works very well on Android 4.** devices, but then, I try on a 2.3 device and the map now looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVEeb.png).

**No map**, but the UI looks fine, and the distance between the two points sounds good.

I would like to know what's wrong, and I assume it's not a Google API key problem since my app works on more recent devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you test both devices under the same conditions?It looks like a connectivity issue. It seems the 2.3 device is not downloading headers completely, try to test it using WiFi.

Comment: Seems like  a mapkey issue. Might be a compatibility issue. But looks like if key was missing

Comment: @AndersMetnik if it was a map key problem you wouldn't see the grid

Comment: @Emmanuel Same connection on all devices, and I just checked, I have the net on the 2.3 device. But I dont understand the Wifi part. Can I connect my device (smartphone) on internet with an other way than Wifi? (sorry for dumb question)

Comment: well if you have a data plan with your provider, you can use the phone's network to connect(i.e. 3g). That might lead to poor or inconsistent connectivity.

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot 3g, 4g, etc... Indeed. But I think I can't since this phone has so sim card.

Comment: do you have the latest version of Google Play Services?

Comment: Yes I think. I don't know if it's a good information but Google Map was very laggy on this device, it was refreshing each 2 seconds. I just updated it, and it works fine now.

Comment: so is your map displaying now?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't finish my sentence. No it still doesn't work. :s

Comment: Ok, it works now, like magic. Maybe it was because of this Google Map update but I did it 30 min ago and it works only now. Strange but it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Try Hardware acceleration when you set the view.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

EDIT : Apparently the link I pointed to is says HW Acceleration is only for 3.0+

Thanks @WarrenFaith

Comment: Ok thanks, I barely know what Hardware acceleration is, but i'll learn.
Just a last question, my problem comes from my app or my device?

Comment: Usually how I figure out what is wrong, I have to figure out what is right and then work from there. Since your app works on 4.+, it is probably your device.  Try the @Kasas answer and make sure the device is signed into Google services

Answer (score -2):

Since you see the grid, this is not an API key related issue. When the key is wrong, you can see only gray background and zoom buttons.

This is a connectivity issue. Make sure your device can reach internet and download tiles.

Comment: Well my app finds the marker position with an address, so i assume that my app can reach internet and even swap information with google server.
So, sadly, i think the problem isn't here, or maybe i've missed something

Comment: Hardware acceleration enabled?

Comment: No, I don't think so, since I don't know how to do it on Android.

Comment: @Bernie have you added all the required permissions, i.e. `com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES`? Whoever downvoted this and other answers should at least explain why they did it.

Comment: Yes I have all permissions needed :s

Comment: @Bernie Interesting issue. Are the devices in the same network (wifi)? Have you tried uninstalling and then installing the app on 2.3 device?

Comment: Yes, same network for all devices and no, I didn't try uninstalling it.  But when you launch you app on a device with eclipse, it's not uninstalled then reinstalled?

Comment: @Bernie No. It is only reinstalled and old cached files are kept. Can you tell one more thing: what versions of Google Play services are on each device? You can check that in Settings app under Manage Applications.

Comment: Google Play Service is 4.0.34 for all my devices :s

Comment: @Bernie Have you enabled "Google Maps Android API v2" on https://cloud.google.com/console#/project ?

Answer (score -2):

You have to check that the device has OpenGL v2 support:

> Specify requirement for OpenGL ES version 2
>
> The Google Maps Android API uses OpenGL ES version 2 to render the
>   map. If OpenGL ES version 2 is not installed, your map will not
>   appear. We recommend that you add the following  element
>   as a child of the  element in AndroidManifest.xml:
>
> This notifies external services of the requirement. In particular, it has the effect of preventing Google
>   Play Store from displaying your app on devices that don't support
>   OpenGL ES version 2.

Here you have the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=es#specify_requirement_for_opengl_es_version_2

Comment: Ok thanks. I just found a test and it says that my device support OpenGL ES version 2. Damn.

Comment: I think this is the answer, but why I have -2 in it?

Comment: It's not the answer for my case. It was a Google Play Service problem but not sure.
For the downvote, look a this thread, all answers (even my question) are downvoted, I don't know why.

Comment: look for information on LogCat, it will tell you more about it